# AWS : VPC Networking mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc

I have an ecs architecture, which has an application running as a container and a nginx side car container. So each task has 2 containers(nginx+app). These two containers are linked through bridge network mode. We currently observe increase in response time. We suspected it may be because of docker bridge network.So, we are trying to change to aws vpc mode networking. But when we tried to update to aws vpc network mode, it gave us an error 'Links are not supported when networkMode=awsvpc.'. So how to use aws vpc networking for these kind of side car architectures?

Answer (score 0):

Linking is not supported in AWSVPC network mode.you need to use [service discovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html).

**links**

```
Type: string array

Required: no
```

> The link parameter allows containers to communicate with each other
>   without the need for port mappings. Only supported if the network mode
>   of a task definition is set to bridge.

**Note**

> This parameter is not supported for **Windows containers** or tasks using
>   the **awsvpc network mode**.

[task_definition_parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html)